# mounting NFS v4 results in "Invalid argument"

Tags: macos, finder, mount, nas, nfs

I recently bought a Synology NAS. I can mount via SMB and APS properly, but I can't make hard links. So I looked around and tried to use NFS. NFS ver3 does work, but Finder behaves strangely for some folders as if that folder can't be retrieved or the drive has freezed, but in terminal everything worked fine (note: using ffplay to play the file in the folder succeeded, but 'open' says that there are no such file). Then I realize that I can mount using NFS ver 4.1 as the NAS supports it. But then I run into this issue. The command I use to mount it is as follows:

nfsver 3: 
mkdir /Volumes/File
mount_nfs -o rwsize=32768 -o locallocks -o namedattr -o noac -o rdirplus -o nfsv3 jin.local:volume1/File/ /Volumes/File

Output: mount_nfs: option nfsv3 deprecated, use vers=#

nfsver 4: 
mkdir /Volumes/File
mount_nfs -o rwsize=32768 -o locallocks -o namedattr -o noac -o rdirplus -o nfsv4 jin.local:volume1/File/ /Volumes/File

Output: mount_nfs: option nfsv4 deprecated, use vers=#
mount_nfs: can't mount volume1/File/ from jin.local onto /Volumes/File: Invalid argument

---

[image: NFS ver 4.1 is enabled]

[image]

Comment: I had tried without all argument but that don't solve the issue.

Comment: I do not think macOS support v4 of nfs.  You should look into downloading v4.  try brew.  I do not think you can use hard links on networked volumes.

Comment: @historystamp It does. macOS doesn't support v4.1 though. Look at the man page of mount_nfs. NFS supports hard link, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use:

> mount_nfs -o rwsize=32768 -o locallocks -o namedattr -o noac -o
>   rdirplus -o nfsv3 jin.local:volume1/File/ /Volumes/File

Instead try:

> mount_nfs -vers=4  -o rwsize=32768 -o locallocks -o namedattr -o noac
>   -o rdirplus jin.local:volume1/File/ /Volumes/File

or

> mount_nfs -vers=4,rwsize=32768,locallocks,namedattr,noac,rdirplus 
>   jin.local:volume1/File/ /Volumes/File